# How to bind objects using MVVM design pattern?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, swiftui

I'm trying to change below code(1.) to MVVM architecture(2.) but can't figure out how to bind objects.

I think the problem is FirstView only pass value but not actually a Binding Object, I tried some different ways but always stuck on don't know how to assign Binding Object to @Published.

Could somebody please give a few hints?

1. (Works fine)

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State var showSecondView = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showSecondView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show second view")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSecondView) {
            SecondView(showSecondView: self.$showSecondView)
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var showSecondView: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showSecondView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Dismiss")
        }
    }
}
```

2. (MVVM)

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = FirstViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.vm.showSecondView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show second view")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $vm.showSecondView) {
            SecondView2(vm: SecondViewModel(showSecondView: self.vm.showSecondView))
        }
    }
}

class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showSecondView = false
}
```

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: SecondViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.vm.showSecondView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Dismiss")
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showSecondView: Bool

    //Right here, i'm not sure how to bind 'showSecondView' from FirstView
    init(showSecondView: Bool) {
        self.showSecondView = showSecondView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass directly the `Binding<Bool>` to the second VM but in this way, there's no need to have `@Published` var and it also doesn't need to be `ObservableObject` and marked as `@ObservedObject`. There might be a better solution to this.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = FirstViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.vm.showSecondView.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Show second view")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $vm.showSecondView) {
            SecondView(vm: SecondViewModel(showSecondView: self.$vm.showSecondView))
        }
    }
}

class FirstViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showSecondView = false
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var vm: SecondViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.vm.showSecondView.wrappedValue.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("Dismiss")
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewModel {
    var showSecondView: Binding<Bool>

    init(showSecondView: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.showSecondView = showSecondView
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, really helpful.